# A challenging kind of sort in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have multiple companies and each have multiple products. They have been added to an elasticsearch index as documents with following structure:

```
[{ "companyId": 1, "productId": 1, "productName": "c1p1" },
 { "companyId": 1, "productId": 2, "productName": "c1p2" },
 { "companyId": 2, "productId": 3, "productName": "c2p1" },
 { "companyId": 2, "productId": 4, "productName": "c2p2" },
 { "companyId": 3, "productId": 5, "productName": "c3p1" },
 { "companyId": 3, "productId": 6, "productName": "c3p2" }]
```

I need to sort the the documents that are returned from elasticsearch in a way that first product of each company is displayed, then the second product and so on:

```
[{ "companyId": 1, "productId": 1, "productName": "c1p1" },
 { "companyId": 2, "productId": 3, "productName": "c2p1" },
 { "companyId": 3, "productId": 5, "productName": "c3p1" },
 { "companyId": 1, "productId": 2, "productName": "c1p2" },
 { "companyId": 2, "productId": 4, "productName": "c2p2" },
 { "companyId": 3, "productId": 6, "productName": "c3p2" }]
```

This can be achieved in SQL Server by using "PARTITION BY companyId". But I couldn't found any way to do this in elasticsearch.

I am aware that using aggregations lets you to group by companyId and then by productId. But my objects have many fields and I need to return the full document in the search result.

Answer (score 0):

In elasticsearch sort query is array, so you can sort by multiple fields, look at
[Sort documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the following sort clause to sort elastic document on multiple fields
Sort first by productid and then by companyid.

```
{
    "sort": [{
        "productid": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    }, {
        "companyid": {
            "order": "desc"
        }
    }],
    "size": 100
}
```

Thanks

Comment: This will sort by productId and then by companyId. productId is unique which means the companyId sort has no effect in this case. The sort I am after is first product of each company and then second product of each company and so on.

Comment: ok, sorry i misunderstood your problem, i will update the answer